# AngularJs: ng-disabled not working in event.target.setAttribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**JS**

```
$scope.change = function(event){ 
       event.target.innerHTML = "connecting <i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin' 
                  aria-hidden='true'></i>";
       event.target.setAttribute("ng-disabled",true); 
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn-invite"  ng-click="change($event)">Connect <i class="fa fa-plug" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
```

It is not disabling the button ?

Comment: Correct your function name ng-click="chage($event)">

Comment: I have updated the question..can u tell me the answer now

Comment: Bind your function to $scope in the controller

Comment: You have to use `$compile` when you modify directives in the dom. Put that directive on the button and toggle a variable to activate it

Comment: can you please give me the demo

Comment: Read the `ng-disabled` docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ng-disabled to disabled inside controller

```
$scope.change = function(event){ 
       event.target.innerHTML = "connecting <i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin' 
                  aria-hidden='true'></i>";
       event.target.setAttribute("disabled",true); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

from angular ng-click  you not be able to call javascript function directly you have to define in controller and call from angular js html
like as

Controller Code:

```
$scope.change = function (event) {
    event.target.innerHTML = "connecting <i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin' 
    aria - hidden = 'true' > < /i>";
    event.target.setAttribute("ng-disabled", true);
}
```

Working Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/5V6n6K0BhH1tcQ2LOTpl

Comment: can you please give me the demo